# Asus G75VX fails to boot after BIOS reset to defaults

Tags: boot, asus-laptop

I have a 3 year old [Asus G75VX](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G75VX/) and after going into the BIOS menu using F8/ESC and resetting back to defaults my computer fails to start.

After pressing the power button I think the laptop is going through POST as the HDD/Numpad indicators blink on and off, I can hear the HDDs spinning and the fans start to spin. However the display doesn't turn on whatsoever. There is no backlight and it doesn't show me the OEM logo like it used to. Instead the laptop seems to go into a wait state as nothing happens. The HDD indicator turns off and nothing else happens.

So far I've tried resetting the BIOS to factory settings using the "remove battery and hold power button" method, swapping HDD positions just in case it's a bootloader issue, making sure that the connector for the display isn't loose, resetting CMOS by removing battery and removing the RAM. Nothing seems to change the computer's new failing bootup sequence. Asus told me it might be a hardware issue but they didn't sound sure. Now I'm thinking that either the motherboard is damaged or the GPU is dead.

Sending the laptop back to Asus for repair isn't an option and a local repair shop couldn't figure out the issue. After searching the web (including SU), similar issues don't have a definite answer so I'm looking for any last minute suggestions I could try.

Comment: GPU seems to be working fine. Probably a corrupt BIOS but the ctrl+HOME reset method seems to be make the BIOS reset (judging from the indicators and delayed keyboard lighting) but after that it's all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the BIOS chip after all. I bought a new one from BIOS Depot and replace it by soldering it on the motherboard.